# Why does my circuit breaker trip after using an oven for 15 minutes?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, safety

I recently moved into a new apartment, and found that when I leave the oven running for about 15 minutes, the circuit breaker trips.

The oven is a [Zanussi ZOB31471XK](https://www.johnlewis.com/zanussi-zob31471xk-built-in-multifunction-single-oven-stainless-steel/p3300374). The label on the appliance gives its max. power as 2790 kW. I find that hard to believe. The spec I linked says 13 A, and 2790 W at 230 V means is close to 13 A, so I believe it was supposed to read 2.790 kW.

The [circuit breaker](https://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Products/HGADA120U.html) can hold 20 A. If the labeling on the distribution board is correct, nothing but the oven is in this circuit.

But then, why does the circuit breaker trip (and should I be worried)?

Comment: As it's an RCBO, it offers RCD protection (earth leakage protection) as well as overcurrent. This may point to the oven's insulation breaking down when hot. It may not be overcurrent, as little as 20mA leaking onto earth should trip the RCD. Get that appliance tested!

Comment: This sounds like a short circuit that is caused by thermal expansion. Does the circuit breaker trip even faster if you switch the grill on? If you look at the circular heating element at the back of the oven, as well as you can with a fan in the way, are there any lumpy bits on the element (which would indicate that the insulation inside has a problem)?

Comment: Had to know... this is what a 3 MW oven is for: [3MW induction furnace](https://www.heattreattoday.com/heat-treat-news/manufacturing-heat-treat-news/steel-dynamics-expands-rolling-mill-includes-3-mw-induction-furnace/)

Comment: How long does it take, after the breaker trips, before you can reset it?   If it takes at least a few minutes, you may have enough time to quickly do some electrical diagnostics inside and find the fault.

Answer (score 2):

Good news: The circuit protection works as intended.
Bad news: The oven is broken.

As suggested already in comments, it can be caused by faulty insulation in the heating element. It can be one of the options or both.

1. Something near heating element is causing a short-circuit and the MCB part of the "breaker" breaks the circuit.
2. Something near heating element is causing hot or neutral wire touching the ground. This current leakage gets detected by RCD part and it breaks the circuit.

As it takes some time it suggests it is heat-related.

Get it repaired. Heating elements may be faulty yet it is impossible to detect it visually. One of my colleagues was building experimental furnace and one faulty heating element cost him a lot of time troubleshooting why the hell it is tripping the RCD after reaching 300°C...

Comment: The good news is that oven elements are pretty cheap, and fairly easy to fit - IF you can be confident which bit is breaking down.

Comment: What is the trip time for currents which only go slightly above nominal - say in the 20-30A range on a 20A breaker? What I mean is, could this be also caused by the oven constantly drawing, say, 22A?

Comment: @JanDorniak The B-class breaker should stand 6-times increased current for less htan 0.4s. For 1.13 increase (22A) it shall last for more than hour. It would need to exceed the current rating by 50% (30A) to trip within an hour.

Comment: @Crowley that still tells me that, while likely, it doesn't *have* to be heat related. (22A was just a random number, seems it'd somewhere in the 40-60A range, maybe higher, doesn't matter). Either way, that oven needs servicing.

Comment: @JanDorniak The heat-relation was based on the 15 minutes delay when the oven heats up closer to its working temperature. As a result something may expand a bit and make the unwanted contact. Was the breaking condition heat-independent it would most likely cause the tripping almost instantly. Unlucliky we do not know wheher it was RCD or MCB trigger to shut it off.